# how to place two grids next to each other

Tags: css, css-grid

[image: grid]
I am trying to move the rectangles next to the square. Since 3 of them won't fit, I'd like only 2 of them to go next to it and the rest of the rectangles to go on the row beneath.

So far I have something like the following:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="rectangles"> rectangles go in here </div>
</div>
```

```
.outer {

}

.square {
  grid-template-colums: 'repeat(12, 1fr)'
}

.rectangle {
  grid-template-colums: '4fr 4fr 4fr'
}
```

I suspect it's something on the outer div but no combination I made made it work.

Comment: You'd have to change the structure. Grid don't wrap like that

Answer (score 1):

Don't apply grid columns to the children, apply it to the parent and tell the rectangles to span 4 columns.

Then flatten the structure to remove the rectangles wrapper.

```css
.outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 8vw);
  margin: 1em;
}

.outer * {
  height: 8.333vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.square {
  width: 8.333vw;
  justify-self: center;
}

.rect {
  grid-column: span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make `outer` be a grid too ... so both containers can share the same cell.

but how do you expect elements to wrap ?

example:

```css
.outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.square,
.rectangle:before {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.rectangles {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.rectangles::before {
  content: '';
}

.square,
p {
  height: 50px;
  border: solid;
  margin: 3px;
}

p {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}

.square {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  margin-inline: auto;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  font-size:3em;
  line-height:0.8;
  color:red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="square"> - </div>
  <div class="rectangles">
    <p>rect</p>
    <p>rect</p>
    <p>rect</p>
    <p>rect</p>
    <p>rect</p>
    <p>rect</p>
    <p>rect</p>
    <p>rect</p>
    <p>rect</p>
    <p>rect</p>
    <p>rect</p>
    <p>rect</p>
    <p>rect</p>
    <p>rect</p>
    <p>rect</p>
  </div>
</div>
```